# Difference between these python code samples?

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and I'm trying to figure out the following below two python code samples. Both code looks same but printing a different result. The main function of the code is divisor summation.

**CODE 1:**

```
def divisor_sum(n):
   no_div = 0
   tot = int(n / 2) + 1
   for i in range(1,tot):
        if n % i == 0:
          no_div += 1
   print no_div
```

**CODE 2:**

```
def divisor2(m):
    max_div = int(m / 2) + 1
    val = 0
    for x in range(1, max_div):
        if m % x == 0:
            val += x
    print val
```

when calling the function?

```
divisor_sum(6)
divisor2(6)
```

**Code ouput:**

```
3
6
```

How it is producing two different results when both code samples are same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly the same code:

CODE 1:

```
no_div += 1
```

CODE 2:

```
val += x
```

Answer (score 1):

The first variant increments by `1` when a divisor is encountered:

```
no_div += 1
```

The second variant increments by the divisor:

```
val += x
```

This means that the first variant counts the number of divisors. The second variant sums the values of the divisors.

The divisors of `6` are `1`, `2` and `3`. So, there are a total of `3` divisors whose values sum to `6`.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of the one given by @dreyescat

Comment: @David But for no of divisor for six is four and its printing 3. any idea ?

Comment: @Stux it doesn't include the number itself when counting divisors. That's the `/ 2`.

Comment: I'm glad my explanations helped

Answer (score 0):

Code in first function i.e divisor_sum() will be giving you the count of divisors of a number (then name of function is misleading). On the other hand code in the second function i.e divisor2() will give you sum of all the divisors of a number.

both function has different code :

divisor_sum() has : "no_div += 1 " that means increment no_div by 1
divisor2() has :"val += x"  which means increment the value of val by x i.e if x=2 then val will become val+2.